# How to copy a member function of another class into myclass in python?

Tags: python, reflection

I have a utility class from which I want to use one of the member function in another class. I don't want to inherit from that class. I just want to re-use the code from one of the member function of the other class. Kind of partial inheritance.

```
class HugeClass():
   def interestedFunc(self,arg1):
      doSomething(self.someMember1)
   def OtherFunctions(self):
      ...



class MyClass():
   def __init__(self):
      self.someMember1 = "myValue"
      self.interestedFunc = MagicFunc(HugeClass.interestedFunc)

c = MyClass()
print c.interestedFunc(arg)
```

Is there such a `MagicFunc` in python?

Comment: Couldn't the `doSomething` function be defined outside of any class, and called it in both `HugeClass` and `MyClass`? If that can't be done, then I'd say there's something wrong with your design (and maybe you need a common base class).

Comment: @Rik I don't have control over the HugeClass. It is part of a framework. Yes, it is a hack. I just want to get getaway with minimal change.:(

Comment: Why don't you subclass `HugeClass`?

Comment: @Avaris In some scenarios, it might be useful to copy just one or two methods from one class to another class instead of subclassing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do what you want ie.:

```
class Foo(object):
    def foo(self):
        print self.a

class Bar(object):
    foo = Foo.__dict__['foo']

b = Bar()
b.a = 1
b.foo()
```

But are you sure that this is good idea?

Comment: The reference to dict is unnecessary.

Comment: That is not working. You will get an error like `unbound method foo() must be called with Foo instance as first argument.`

Comment: @NiklasR: It doesn't work only if you follow *Marcin* suggestion, but `Foo.__dict__['foo']` should work fine: [link](http://ideone.com/B1riI)

Comment: It remains the case that it is unncessary to reference `__dict__`: `Foo.foo.im_func` will work just as well, and will also work for classes that lack a `__dict__` property.

Comment: Using `foo = Foo.foo` works fine in Py3, where the difference between "bound" and "unbound" methods no longer exists.

Comment: `Foo.foo.im_func` is CPython specific and may not work in other Python implementations.

Comment: @Marcin: I am not aware of any classes without a `__dict__`.  `__slots__` suppress *instance* dictionaries.

Comment: @Marcin: Just because it doesn't show up in [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#dir) doesn't mean it's not there.  Try [`print Foo.__dict__.items()`](http://ideone.com/1RIr4)

Comment: @EthanFurman CPython is the reference implementation. Why do you believe that providing `im_func` is not required for a fully compliant implementation?

Comment: @Marcin: CPython is indeed the reference implementation **. . .** of the *Python Language*.  The Python language specifies being able to create functions using the `def` keyword; it does not specify that the created functions must be implemented by being stored in an `im_func` attribute.

Comment: @EthanFurman Incorrect. The same page you just linked does in fact specify that.

Comment: @Marcin: Really?  Did you notice the command that was fed into `print()`?  `Foo.` **\_\_dict\_\_** `.items()`?  Remember, our disagreement is about whether or not a class that specifies `__slots__` has a dict, and this `Foo` has `__slots__` and has a dict, or I wouldn't have been able to print the dict items.  A `Foo` instance (`Foo()`) would not have a dict, but the `Foo` class does.

Comment: @EthanFurman We are also disagreeing about the availability of im_func. `im_func` is required, as per the page you linked.

Comment: @Marcin: The page I linked says nothing about `im_func`, it's about printing `__dict__.items()`.

Comment: @Marcin: When in doubt, go to the source **. . .** I asked on [python-dev](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-March/117491.html) about `im_func` (renamed to just `__func__` in Python 3), and it is indeed required.  Good call.  Keep in mind, though, that just because CPython has it doesn't mean it's required -- the GIL, for example, is not.

Comment: @EthanFurman I know that mere presence in Cpython does not make a requirement, which is why I have repeatedly referred you to the document that oays down the requirement, notwithstanding that you continue to deny that. If in doubt, actually read the specifications.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the `__dict__` part from the older answer is not required in Python 3

This works fine:

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self):
        print self.a

class Bar:
    foo = Foo.foo

b = Bar()
b.a = 1
b.foo()
```