# Apply a method to an object of another class

Tags: python

Given two non-related classes A and B, how to call `A.method` with an object of B as `self`?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def print_x(self):
        print self.x

class B:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

a = A('spam')
b = B('eggs')

a.print_x() #<-- spam
<magic>(A.print_x, b) #<-- 'eggs'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a member function of another class into myclass in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646187/how-to-copy-a-member-function-of-another-class-into-myclass-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python 3.x you can simply do what you want:

```
A.print_x(b) #<-- 'eggs'
```

If you only have an instance of 'A', then get the class first:

```
a.__class__.print_x(b) #<-- 'eggs'
```

In Python 2.x (which the OP uses) this doesn't work, as noted by the OP and explained by Amber in the comments:

> *This is a difference between Python 2.x and Python 3.x - methods in
>    3.x don't enforce being passed the same class.*

### More details (OP edit)

In python 2, `A.print_x` returns an "unbound method", which cannot be directly applied to other classes' objects:

> When an unbound user-defined method object is called, the underlying function (im_func) is called, with the restriction that the first argument must be an instance of the proper class (im_class) or of a derived class thereof. >> http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

To work around this restriction, we first have to obtain a "raw" function from a method, via `im_func` or `__func__` (2.6+), which then can be called passing an object. This works on both classes and instances:

```
# python 2.5-
A.print_x.im_func(b)    
a.print_x.im_func(b)

# python 2.6+
A.print_x.__func__(b)   
a.print_x.__func__(b)
```

In python 3 there's no such thing anymore as unbound method.

> Unbound methods are gone for good. ClassObject.method returns an
>   ordinary function object, instance.method still returns a bound
>   method object. >> http://www.python.org/getit/releases/3.0/NEWS.txt

Hence, in python 3, `A.print_x` is just a function, and can be called right away and `a.print_x` still has to be unbounded:

```
# python 3.0+
A.print_x(b)
a.print_x.__func__(b)
```

Comment: "TypeError: unbound method print_x() must be called with A instance as first argument (got B instance instead)".

Comment: @thg435: Which version of Python are you using? I tested on `3.2.1 (default, Jul 10 2011, 21:51:15) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]` and it works. Maybe you have to derive from object in Python 2.x.

Comment: yes, I should have noted that I'm using 2.7. Deriving from object doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, this is a difference between Python 2.x and Python 3.x - methods in 3.x don't enforce being passed the same class.

Comment: @WolframH: Could you incorporate Amber's point in your answer, ideally with a short explanation about unbound methods removed in python3, so that we have a good reference response to this question.

Comment: @WolframH: thanks. I took a liberty to add some more details to your answer, hope that's fine with you.

Comment: @thg435: THank you very much. It's **really helpful** now, and I learned a lot. This question turned out to be more interesting than I thought :-)

Answer (score 4):

You don't (well, it's not that you can't throw enough magic at it to make it work, it's that you just shouldn't). If the function is supposed to work with more than one type, make it... a function.

```
# behold, the magic and power of duck typing
def fun(obj):
    print obj.x

class A:
    x = 42

class B:
    x = 69

fun(A())
fun(B())
```

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Inheritance implies a strong relation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you would really want to do this, but it *is* possible:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         print self.a
...
>>> class B(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = "b"
...
>>> x = A()
>>> y = B()
>>> x.foo.im_func(y)
b
>>> A.foo.im_func(y)
b
```

An instance method (a class instance's bound method) has a property called `im_func` which refers to the actual function called by the instance method, without the instance/class binding. The class object's version of the method also has this property.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question for py2. As a side note, `im_func` is deprecated in favor of `__func__` since 2.6.