# Using class methods without `@classmethod`

Tags: python, class, methods, semantics

Consider:

```
class cla(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val

    def met(self):
        return self.val + 1
```

Then `cla.met(cla(1))` returns `2`.

Since I don't need an instance of class  `cla` to use method `met`, does this mean it is a class method, even though I haven't used the decorator `@classmethod`?

I read https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods to understand better what class methods are, but somehow it seems to me that the intended meaning of `@classmethod` is already present in the normal methods of a class - and I'm actually quite confused from the examples for there, as they don't even compile.

Comment: Somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935241/python-call-instance-method-using-func

Answer (score 1):

If you have an instance of class `cla`:

```
instance = cla(1)
```

Then the following two calls are equivalent:

```
instance.met()
cla.met(instance)
```

Note that the second only works if you pass it an argument with a `val` attribute (so you actually **do** need sth. resembling an instance of class `cla`), while the first implicitly calls the function defined on the class and passes itself as an argument. See [docs on method objects](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects). The following lines could help shed some light on the internals of a method object:

```
>>> f = cla.met
>>> m = instance.met
>>> type(f)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(m)
<class 'method'>
>>> m.__self__ == instance
True
>>> m.__func__ == f
True
```

So

```
>>> f(instance)
2
```

is the same as

```
>>> m.__func__(m.__self__)
2
```

which is what `instance.met()` (aka `m()` aka `m.__call__()`) does under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

`cla.met(cla(1))` is just a convoluted way of saying `cla(1).met()`. The answer is simply no: `met` is not a class method.

A class method would be

```
class cla():
   @classmethod
   def met(cls, val):
       return val + 1
```

which would be called as `cla.met(1)`

Hope this clarifies the difference.