# Why does the implementation of _make_id return a tuple of two id when pass an instance method?

Tags: django

I read the source of Django and I am interested at the [implemenation about signal](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py#L9). Actually, I wonder why the function `_make_id` returns different things which depends on arguments passed.

the following code is what I am talking about

```
def _make_id(target):
    if hasattr(target, '__func__'):
        return (id(target.__self__), id(target.__func__))
    return id(target)
```

Is there any reason not to just return the `id(target)`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but I think it's because the instance method implies it's bound to something and you want to make sure that address travels with the function ID, for architectural reasons I'm sure were carefully considered. More here in this old SO thread about what `__func__` does: [python - call instance method using __func__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935241/python-call-instance-method-using-func)